# Change Date to a string on the local time zone of the device

Tags: java, android

I am getting a `Date` datatype from the database like this `Mon Sep 14 11:30:00 GMT+03:00 2020`.I want to change this value to a string so I used this function.

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";


public static String dateToString(Date date){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(General.DATE_FORMAT);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    if(date == null)
        return "";
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

This function is given me this output `2020-09-14 11:30` but it should be `2020-09-14 02:30` according to my android device time zone. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just remove this line `dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`java.time`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) for this, it is made available to lower Android API levels via [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // (nearly) your example pattern for output (u is better here)
    final String DATE_FORMAT = "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm";
    // use it to create an output formatter
    DateTimeFormatter outputDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    // your example String
    String exampleDate = "Mon Sep 14 11:30:00 GMT+03:00 2020";
    // parse it with a suitable formatter using a specific pattern and a Locale for names
    DateTimeFormatter parserDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O uuuu",
                                                                Locale.ENGLISH);
    // then parse the example String
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(exampleDate, parserDtf);
    // get your local offset (the one of your device)
    ZoneOffset localOffset = OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset();
    // and adjust the offset to your local one
    OffsetDateTime localOdt = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(localOffset);
    // and output it (on android, use log...)
    System.out.println(odt.format(outputDtf));  // example datetime
    System.out.println(localOdt.format(outputDtf)); // same time in local offset
}
```

This code outputs

```
2020-09-14 11:30
2020-09-14 10:30
```

**Please note** that the output has — of course — taken my current offset, which is UTC+02:00.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the `getDefault()` method of **Locale**

```
public static String dateToString(Date date){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(General.DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    if(date == null)
        return "";
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Hope it will work for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try set it before

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```